# What is the optimal losing move?

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

*I had a hard time trying to find the best-suited stackexchange site to ask this question. I'm still not sure whether this is the right place, so please guide me to the right one if you think this is off-topic.*

In turned based games with perfect information without randomness and with end results among win, loss, and draw (such as go, chess, reversi, tic-tac-toe etc.), it is possible to search through the game tree by brute-force and conclude the result of a certain board position.

With a board position `P`, there are `m_0 .. m_n` possible moves for the current player, and `m_0` appears to be the winning move. Let's say there are two players `B` and `W` in this game, and now it's `B`'s turn. `B` plays `m_0` and will win the game unless he makes mistakes in the responses to `W`'s later moves. Let's assume that both player do not make mistakes at all. At this point `W` really has no reason to play the game further because whatever move she makes, she knows she will lose.

Still, I was wondering whether there exists a 'best losing move' for `W`. Is there such thing? If so, how can it be determined?

Comment: You have to define 'best losing move'. Do you mean the move that makes the game last longer ?

Comment: @joriki, why isn't this [tag:combinatorial-game-theory]?

Comment: @krirkrirk that seems to be his question; if such a concept exists.  @ xiver, even in the case that `W` cannot reach a *winning* position, in several games, `W` might still have the ability to prevent `B` from winning causing a stalemate either by causing the game to last indefinitely, or by putting the game into a position that the win condition for `B` can no longer be satisfied.

Comment: @JMoravitz If `W` can lead to a stalemate, then that board position is a draw position for `B`, not a winning position.

Comment: In which case, still there does exist the idea as krirkrirk says of "making the game last longer."  Consider the question of connect-four.  If player `B` begins the game by playing one piece in the center column, it is known that with perfect play by both players that player `B` will win.  Compare the scenario of losing as player `W` with a full board having done everything they could to delay the game, to the scenario of allowing `B` to make a four-in-a-row with his first four pieces.

Comment: @HenningMakholm and xiver77: Sorry about the erroneous tag edit.

Comment: In *Winning Ways* Berlekamp et al call this the " Enough Rope principle "; you might check the index for that.

Answer (score 0):

In many games, including Go as it is usually played, there is a score at the end of the game, so you can use that to compare losing moves. You might say a best losing move is one where the difference in score is as small as possible at the end of the game.

More generally, in a game where you lose when you can't make a move, the game will eventually be something like "a number of free moves for the winner", and the best losing moves could be said to be the ones that minimize that number. This is related to the concept of left and right stops in combinatorial game theory. Which are standard material in textbooks like "Lessons in Play: An Introduction to Combinatorial Game Theory", but are also featured in this tidy summary paper: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Ye.pdf